# What is the character encoding of this file?

Tags: character-encoding, mbcs

- file extension is `.PRO`
- is decoded correctly by Notepad(!)
- is decoded correctly by Python via `dbcs` codec, but only on Windows
- most other programs (file, chardet, sublime-text, ...) incorrectly classify it as UTF-8 (and accordingly display Chinese characters)
- it seems like every *three* bytes encode *two* characters

You would think (3) would settle it ("it's an East Asian multi-byte encoding"), but then why don't chardet et al. detect it?

Here is the `hexdump -C` of it along with the ANSI output of Notepad.

```
00000000  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  |................|
00000010  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  |................|
00000020  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  |................|
00000030  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  ad e0 b4 ad e2 80 8a e2  |................|
00000040  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  e2 80 a0 e4 b4 a0 e4 b1  |................|
00000050  85 e4 9d 81 e5 98 a0 e6  8d a1 e6 ad b5 e6 85 ac  |................|
00000060  e2 81 b6 e3 84 b3 e4 88  ad e0 a8 8d e2 b4 ad e2  |................|
00000070  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  |................|
00000080  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  |................|
00000090  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  |................|
000000a0  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e0 b4 ad  e0 b4 8a e5 80 8a e6 bd  |................|
000000b0  b2 e7 89 a7 e6 b5 a1 e2  81 ad e2 80 a0 e3 a8 a0  |................|
000000c0  e5 94 a0 e6 a5 ae e6 95  b6 e7 8d b2 e6 b1 a1 e5  |................|
000000d0  80 ad e6 bd b2 e7 89 a7  e6 b5 a1 e0 b5 ad e2 80  |................|
000000e0  8a e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  |................|
000000f0  e2 80 a0 e3 84 a0 e3 90  b3 e4 8e b0 e7 98 a0 e7  |................|
00000100  89 a5 e6 85 b0 e6 ad a3  e0 b5 b4 e4 90 8a e7 91  |................|
00000110  a1 e6 b5 b5 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 a8 a0  |................|
00000120  e3 84 a0 e2 b8 b5 e3 8c  b0 e3 88 ae e3 84 b0 e0  |................|
00000130  b4 b3 e5 94 8a e7 89 a8  e6 95 ba e7 91 a9 e2 80  |................|
00000140  a0 e2 80 a0 e3 a8 a0 e3  84 a0 e3 a8 b7 e3 94 b4  |................|
00000150  e3 8c ba e2 80 b0 e2 80  a0 e2 a0 a0 e7 91 93 e7  |................|
00000160  89 a1 e2 a5 b4 e0 a8 8d  e6 a1 83 e7 89 a1 e6 95  |................|
00000170  a7 e4 b8 a0 e2 b9 b2 e2  80 a0 e2 80 ba e3 8c a0  |................|
00000180  e0 a8 8d e2 b4 ad e2 b4  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  |................|
00000190  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  |................|
000001a0  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  |................|
000001b0  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  ad e2 b4 ad e0 b4 ad e0  |................|
000001c0  b4 8a e5 98 8a e7 89 af  e6 95 a8 e7 a9 a9 e6 b9  |................|
000001d0  b5 e2 81 a7 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 88 b1  |................|
000001e0  e2 b8 b0 e2 80 b8 e4 8e  b0 e0 a8 8d e4 a5 81 e3  |................|
000001f0  99 8e e2 80 ba e6 95 8c  e7 91 a9 e6 95 b7 e7 91  |................|
00000200  b2 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e3 88 a0 eb 94 a0  |................|
00000210  e2 bd 93 e6 b5 a3 e0 a8  8d e0 a8 8d e7 89 90 e6  |................|
00000220  9d af e6 85 b2 e6 b5 ad  e6 8d b3 e7 89 a8 e7 91  |................|
00000230  a9 e2 81 b4 e2 80 a0 e7  89 84 e6 8d b5 e2 81 ab  |................|
00000240  e5 90 a0 e6 b5 a5 e6 95  b0 e6 85 b2 e2 b9 b4 e5  |................|
00000250  a8 a0 e6 a5 a5 e2 81 b4  e0 a8 8d e2 80 a0 e2 80  |................|
00000260  a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  |................|
00000270  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e6 88  a0 e7 89 a1 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
00000280  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e4 8e b0  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e6 b4  |................|
00000290  a0 e6 b9 a9 e0 b4 a0 e0  b4 8a e5 8c 8a e6 85 b4  |................|
000002a0  e7 91 b2 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
000002b0  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  e2 b8 b0 e3 98 b0 e2 80  |................|
000002c0  a0 e2 80 a0 e3 98 a0 e2  b8 b8 e2 80 b1 e3 80 a0  |................|
000002d0  e3 a8 b0 e3 80 b0 e0 a8  8d e2 b8 b1 e7 89 86 e6  |................|
000002e0  ad a1 e6 a5 b4 e6 b9 af  e6 95 a9 e7 95 b2 e6 9d  |................|
000002f0  ae e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  |................|
00000300  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e0 a8 8d e2 80 a0 e7  |................|
00000310  99 85 e6 ad a1 e6 a5 b5  e7 89 a5 e6 b9 b5 e2 81  |................|
00000320  a7 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3  80 ad e3 a4 ae e2 80 b2  |................|
00000330  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 98  b6 e3 90 ae e2 80 a0 e3  |................|
00000340  88 b0 e3 88 ba e0 b4 b9  e2 80 8a e4 90 a0 e6 b5  |................|
00000350  a1 e6 99 b0 e6 a5 a5 e6  b1 ae e7 8d a1 e2 81 b3  |................|
00000360  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 b8  b0 e3 80 b4 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
00000370  80 a0 e3 80 b1 e2 b8 b8  e2 80 b3 e3 80 a0 e3 a8  |................|
00000380  b4 e3 80 b5 e0 a8 8d e2  b8 b2 e7 89 86 e6 ad a1  |................|
00000390  e6 a5 b4 e6 b9 af e6 95  a9 e7 95 b2 e6 9d ae e2  |................|
000003a0  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  |................|
000003b0  a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e0  a8 8d e2 80 a0 e7 99 85  |................|
000003c0  e6 ad a1 e6 a5 b5 e7 89  a5 e6 b9 b5 e2 81 a7 e2  |................|
000003d0  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 80 ad  e3 a0 ae e2 80 b2 e2 80  |................|
000003e0  a0 e2 80 a0 e3 a0 b6 e3  94 ae e2 80 a0 e3 9c b0  |................|
000003f0  e3 80 ba e0 b4 b3 e2 80  8a e4 90 a0 e6 b5 a1 e6  |................|
00000400  99 b0 e6 a5 a5 e6 b1 ae  e7 8d a1 e2 81 b3 e2 80  |................|
00000410  a0 e2 80 a0 e2 b8 b0 e3  84 b4 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  |................|
00000420  e3 80 b1 e2 b8 b9 e2 80  b6 e3 80 a0 e3 a8 b8 e3  |................|
00000430  90 b5 e0 a8 8d e2 b8 b3  e7 89 86 e6 ad a1 e6 a5  |................|
00000440  b4 e6 b9 af e6 95 a9 e7  95 b2 e6 9d ae e2 80 a0  |................|
00000450  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
00000460  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e0 a8 8d  e2 80 a0 e7 99 85 e6 ad  |................|
00000470  a1 e6 a5 b5 e7 89 a5 e6  b9 b5 e2 81 a7 e2 80 a0  |................|
00000480  e2 80 a0 e3 80 ad e3 a0  ae e2 80 b2 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
00000490  80 a0 e3 80 b7 e3 a4 ae  e2 80 a0 e3 84 b1 e3 94  |................|
000004a0  ba e0 b4 b0 e2 80 8a e4  90 a0 e6 b5 a1 e6 99 b0  |................|
000004b0  e6 a5 a5 e6 b1 ae e7 8d  a1 e2 81 b3 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
000004c0  80 a0 e2 b8 b0 e3 80 b4  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 80  |................|
000004d0  b1 e2 b8 b9 e2 80 b5 e3  84 a0 e3 a8 b3 e3 80 b4  |................|
000004e0  e0 a8 8d e7 89 84 e6 8d  b5 e6 85 ab e6 99 b5 e6  |................|
000004f0  85 a2 e2 81 b5 e2 80 a0  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 88  |................|
00000500  a0 e3 80 ae e2 80 b5 e2  80 a0 e3 84 a0 e3 90 b3  |................|
00000510  e3 84 ae e2 80 a0 e3 98  b1 e3 80 ba e0 b4 b6 e5  |................|
00000520  8c 8a e6 95 b4 e6 a5 b2  e2 b9 ac e4 88 a0 e6 9d  |................|
00000530  a5 e6 b9 a9 e2 81 ae e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 b8 b2  |................|
00000540  e3 94 b0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e3 8c b1 e2 b8 b4 e2  |................|
00000550  80 b1 e3 84 a0 e3 a8 b6  e3 98 b0 e0 a8 8d e7 91  |................|
00000560  93 e7 89 a5 e6 b1 a9 e2  80 ae e6 b9 85 e6 95 a4  |................|
00000570  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e3 88 a0 e3 88 ae e2  |................|
00000580  80 b0 e2 80 a0 e3 84 a0  e3 98 b3 e3 80 ae e2 80  |................|
00000590  a0 e3 84 b2 e3 8c ba e0  b4 b6 e4 90 8a e7 95 b2  |................|
000005a0  e6 ad a3 e6 89 a1 e6 85  ac e7 8d b3 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
000005b0  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  e2 b8 b0 e3 80 b2 e2 80  |................|
000005c0  a0 e2 80 a0 e3 80 b1 e2  b8 b5 e2 80 b2 e3 88 a0  |................|
000005d0  e3 a8 b2 e3 94 b3 e0 a8  8d e6 85 96 e7 95 ab e6  |................|
000005e0  b5 b5 e5 90 ad e6 bd b2  e6 ad a3 e6 95 ae e2 81  |................|
000005f0  ae e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  |................|
00000600  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e0 a8  8d e2 80 a0 e7 89 94 e6  |................|
00000610  8d af e6 b9 ab e6 b9 a5  e4 88 a0 e6 9d a5 e6 b9  |................|
00000620  a9 e2 81 ae e3 80 ad e3  8c ae e2 80 b0 e2 80 a0  |................|
00000630  e2 80 a0 e3 88 b9 e3 84  ae e2 80 a0 e3 88 b2 e3  |................|
00000640  90 ba e0 b4 b9 e2 80 8a  e5 90 a0 e6 bd b2 e6 ad  |................|
00000650  a3 e7 95 ae e6 9d ae e6  91 b3 e7 95 b2 e6 ad a3  |................|
00000660  e2 b4 a0 e2 b8 b0 e3 90  b8 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3  |................|
00000670  a0 a0 e2 b8 b1 e2 80 b5  e3 88 a0 e3 a8 b4 e3 9c  |................|
00000680  b4 e0 a8 8d e2 80 a0 e7  89 94 e6 8d af e6 b9 ab  |................|
00000690  e6 b9 b5 e7 8d a7 e7 89  a4 e6 8d b5 e2 81 ab e3  |................|
000006a0  80 ad e3 a0 ae e2 80 b7  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 8c  |................|
000006b0  b8 e3 90 ae e2 80 a0 e3  98 b2 e3 90 ba e0 b4 b7  |................|
000006c0  e2 80 8a e5 90 a0 e6 bd  b2 e6 ad a3 e7 95 ae e6  |................|
000006d0  9d ae e6 91 b3 e7 95 b2  e6 ad a3 e2 b4 a0 e2 b8  |................|
000006e0  b0 e3 a4 b8 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e3 a0 a0 e2 b8 b0  |................|
000006f0  e2 80 b2 e3 88 a0 e3 a8  b8 e3 9c b4 e0 a8 8d e2  |................|
00000700  80 a0 e7 89 94 e6 8d af  e6 b9 ab e6 b9 b5 e7 8d  |................|
00000710  a7 e7 89 a4 e6 8d b5 e2  81 ab e3 80 ad e3 a4 ae  |................|
00000720  e2 80 b0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e3 9c b7 e3 98 ae e2  |................|
00000730  80 a0 e3 80 b3 e3 90 ba  e0 b4 b7 e2 80 8a e5 90  |................|
00000740  a0 e6 bd b2 e6 ad a3 e7  95 ae e6 9d ae e6 91 b3  |................|
00000750  e7 95 b2 e6 ad a3 e2 b4  a0 e2 b8 b0 e3 80 b9 e2  |................|
00000760  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 9c a0  e2 b8 b6 e2 80 b1 e3 8c  |................|
00000770  a0 e3 a8 b2 e3 9c b4 e0  a8 8d e2 80 a0 e7 89 94  |................|
00000780  e6 8d af e6 b9 ab e6 b9  b5 e7 8d a7 e7 89 a4 e6  |................|
00000790  8d b5 e2 81 ab e3 80 ad  e3 a4 ae e2 80 b1 e2 80  |................|
000007a0  a0 e2 80 a0 e3 94 b7 e3  84 ae e2 80 a0 e3 90 b3  |................|
000007b0  e3 90 ba e0 b4 b7 e2 80  8a e5 90 a0 e6 bd b2 e6  |................|
000007c0  ad a3 e7 95 ae e6 9d ae  e6 91 b3 e7 95 b2 e6 ad  |................|
000007d0  a3 e2 b4 a0 e2 b8 b0 e3  84 b9 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  |................|
000007e0  e3 9c a0 e2 b8 b4 e2 80  b4 e3 8c a0 e3 a8 b6 e3  |................|
000007f0  9c b4 e0 a8 8d e2 80 a0  e7 89 94 e6 8d af e6 b9  |................|
00000800  ab e6 b9 b5 e7 8d a7 e7  89 a4 e6 8d b5 e2 81 ab  |................|
00000810  e3 80 ad e3 a4 ae e2 80  b1 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3  |................|
00000820  90 b7 e3 84 ae e2 80 a0  e3 a0 b3 e3 90 ba e0 b4  |................|
00000830  b7 e2 80 8a e5 90 a0 e6  bd b2 e6 ad a3 e7 95 ae  |................|
00000840  e6 9d ae e6 91 b3 e7 95  b2 e6 ad a3 e2 b4 a0 e2  |................|
00000850  b8 b0 e3 84 b9 e2 80 a0  e2 80 a0 e3 9c a0 e2 b8  |................|
00000860  b3 e2 80 b8 e3 90 a0 e3  a8 b0 e3 9c b4 e0 a8 8d  |................|
00000870  e2 80 a0 e7 89 94 e6 8d  af e6 b9 ab e6 b9 b5 e7  |................|
00000880  8d a7 e7 89 a4 e6 8d b5  e2 81 ab e3 80 ad e3 a4  |................|
00000890  ae e2 80 b1 e2 80 a0 e2  80 a0 e3 8c b7 e3 98 ae  |................|
000008a0  e2 80 a0 e3 88 b4 e3 90  ba e0 b4 b7 e2 80 8a e5  |................|
000008b0  90 a0 e6 bd b2 e6 ad a3  e6 95 ae e2 81 ae e6 b9  |................|
000008c0  85 e6 95 a4 e2 80 a0 e2  b4 a0 e2 b8 b0 e3 9c b8  |................|
000008d0  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 9c  a0 e2 b8 b3 e2 80 b8 e3  |................|
000008e0  90 a0 e3 a8 b2 e3 a4 b4  e0 a8 8d e6 95 82 ef b1  |................|
000008f0  ac e7 91 a6 e6 b9 a5 e2  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  |................|
00000900  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 80  ad e3 88 ae e2 80 b7 e2  |................|
00000910  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e3 94 b7  e3 a4 ae e2 80 a0 e3 8c  |................|
00000920  b4 e3 80 ba e0 b4 b0 e4  94 8a e6 91 ae e2 81 a5  |................|
00000930  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
00000940  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 b8 b0  e3 80 b0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  |................|
00000950  a0 e3 9c a0 e2 b8 b6 e2  80 b9 e3 90 a0 e3 a8 b3  |................|
00000960  e3 88 b1 e0 a8 8d e0 a8  8d e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  |................|
00000970  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  |................|
00000980  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  |................|
00000990  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  |................|
000009a0  b4 ad e0 b4 ad e0 b4 8a  e2 80 8a e2 80 a0 e5 89  |................|
000009b0  90 e4 9d 8f e4 85 92 e4  b5 8d e4 94 a0 e4 99 92  |................|
000009c0  e4 b1 8f e5 89 87 e4 a5  85 e4 a1 83 e4 84 a0 e4  |................|
000009d0  9d 82 e4 b1 85 e5 95 81  e4 95 86 e2 85 8e e0 a8  |................|
000009e0  8d e0 a8 8d e6 95 94 e7  81 ad e7 89 a5 e7 91 a1  |................|
000009f0  e7 89 b5 e2 80 a0 e2 80  a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 ba e3  |................|
00000a00  8c b1 e2 b8 b5 e2 80 b9  e2 ac a0 e2 b8 b0 e2 80  |................|
00000a10  b4 e2 b4 af e2 b8 b0 e2  80 b4 e4 8e b0 e0 a8 8d  |................|
00000a20  e7 89 84 e6 8d b5 e2 81  ab e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2  |................|
00000a30  80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0  e2 80 ba e2 80 a0 e2 b8  |................|
00000a40  b2 e3 a0 b1 e2 ac a0 e2  b8 b0 e3 90 b0 e2 b4 af  |................|
00000a50  e2 b8 b0 e3 90 b0 e6 88  a0 e7 89 a1 e0 a8 8d e7  |................|
00000a60  91 93 e7 89 a5 e6 b1 a9  e7 8d a9 e6 95 a9 e7 a9  |................|
00000a70  b2 e6 a5 a5 e2 81 b4 e2  80 ba e3 94 a0 e6 b4 a0  |................|
00000a80  e6 b9 a9 e3 8c a0 e2 80  b0 e0 b5 b3 e5 94 8a e7  |................|
00000a90  89 a8 e6 95 ba e7 91 a9  e2 80 a0 e2 80 a0 e2 80  |................|
00000aa0  a0 e2 80 a0 e3 a8 a0 e3  84 a0 e3 a8 b8 e3 a0 b2  |................|
00000ab0  e3 90 ba e2 80 b2 e4 94  a8 e6 91 ae e2 a5 a5 e0  |................|
00000ac0  a8 8d e0 a8 8d e2 b4 ad  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  |................|
00000ad0  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  |................|
00000ae0  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4  ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2  |................|
00000af0  b4 ad e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad  e2 b4 ad e2 b4 ad e0 b4  |................|
00000b00  ad e2 80 8a e3 88 a0 e3  98 b3 e2 80 b5 e3 80 b2  |................|
00000b10  e3 a0 b0 e3 88 b0 e3 8c  b1 e2 80 b2 e2 b8 b4 e3  |................|
00000b20  9c b0 e3 90 a0 e3 80 ae  e0 b4 b7 0a e5 89 83 e3  |................|
00000b30  a9 83 e3 80 a0 e3 a5 b8  e4 8d 82 e2 80 b0 e4 99  |................|
00000b40  8d e5 98 a0 e2 b8 b1 e3  80 b8 e4 84 b1 e0 a8 8d  |................|
00000b50  0a                                                |.|
00000b51
```

---

```
---------------------------------------
          MELAG Vacuklav 31-B
---------------------------------------

Programm    : Universal-Programm
              134�C verpackt
Datum       : 15.03.2013
Uhrzeit     : 17:45:30    (Start)
Charge Nr.  :  3
---------------------------------------

Vorheizung       120.8 �C
AIN6: Leitwert       2 �S/cm

Programmschritt   Druck  Temperat. Zeit 
                   bar      �C     min 

Start              0.06     68.1  00:00
1.Fraktionierung                
  Evakuierung     -0.92     66.4  02:29
  Dampfeinlass     0.40    108.3  04:50
2.Fraktionierung                
  Evakuierung     -0.82     68.5  07:03
  Dampfeinlass     0.41    109.6  08:54
3.Fraktionierung                
  Evakuierung     -0.82     70.9  11:50
  Dampfeinlass     0.40    109.5  13:40
Druckaufbau        2.05    134.1  16:06
Steril. Beginn     2.05    134.1  16:06
Steril. Ende       2.20    136.0  21:36
Druckablass        0.20    105.2  22:35
Vakuum-Trocknen               
  Trocknen Beginn -0.30     92.1  22:49
  Trocknungsdruck -0.84     81.5  24:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.87     83.4  26:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.89     80.2  28:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.90     77.6  30:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.90     76.1  32:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.91     75.1  34:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.91     74.4  36:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.91     74.1  38:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.91     73.8  40:47
  Trocknungsdruck -0.91     73.6  42:47
  Trocknen Ende   -0.87     73.8  42:49
Bel�ften          -0.27     75.9  43:00
Ende               0.00     76.9  43:12

---------------------------------------

   PROGRAMM ERFOLGREICH ABGELAUFEN!

Temperatur      : 135.9  +0.4 /-0.4 �C
Druck           :   2.18 +0.04/-0.04 bar
Sterilisierzeit :  5 min 30 s
Uhrzeit         : 18:28:42 (Ende)

---------------------------------------
  2365 200802132 4.07 4.07
 CRC: 0x9BC0 MF V1.801A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the source text was originally [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), a standard single-byte extended ASCII encoding. To produce that hex dump, some process misinterpreted the source text as UTF-16LE (a double-byte encoding) and converted it to UTF-8, which is why many programs you've tried interpreted it as UTF-8.

To manually reverse this process, decode the hex as UTF-8, swap every pair of bytes to account for the endianness, then interpret the resulting bytes as ISO/IEC 8859-1.